# What is the farthest planet from the center of the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars* what is the farthest planet from the center of their galaxy? Does it have life on it? Does it have an appearance in one of the movies?

Comment: Do you mean their *galaxy* instead of universe? Their universe is our universe (it's a galaxy far far away from us) and there's no "center" to the universe.

Comment: yah yah galaxy, and is Coruscant really the center?

Comment: Coruscant is close to the center though not at the exact center, where presumably a supermassive black hole is (as in many galaxies). The closest planet to the galactic center is probably Byss. You can see this in the answer to the question this has been marked as a duplicate of, and the same answer would allow you to find the farthest planet from the galactic center. That planet appears to be the planet of the Red Nebula.

Comment: One Tatooine farm boy's thoughts are: "Well, if there's a bright center to the universe, you're on the planet that it's farthest from."